# What is the best way to find a certain button by a tag?

Tags: c#

I am making a chess game and I do this by giving every button a tag with his x and y:

```
button2.Tag = "21";
```

and then if I want to find the button above it I want to look for the button with the tag "22".

But... How do I do that?

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific - is this concerning a WInForms application?

Comment: Consider putting your buttons into a 2d array, or list of lists, instead. Then you can reference them like `buttons[2][2]`.

Comment: In WinForms, `Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(b => b.Tag == "21")`

Comment: Better to use `FirstOrDefault()` than `Where`, though.

Comment: why not use a multidimensional array to store them by row and column `buttons[x,y]` and then you can find the neighbours a lot easier

Comment: Thanks Blorgbeard, It really makes more sense to just use a 2d array :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have all the buttons in a list and then do a search with a foreach or use linq with where to get the one with the tag number you are looking for.

In case you are in winforms and dont want to create a list of buttons by yourself, another approach is to have a panel that contains all the buttons in the designer. And then in you code you could do panel.Controls and that gives you access to all the controls that are within the panel.

Hope this helps!